# Impossible to search into a tag found after a search

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an other problem with BeautifulSoup. This is my code :

```
def parse_airfields():
    html = urlopen('https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/AIRAC-2015-09-17/html/eAIP/FR-AD-1.3-fr-FR.html').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    # delete <del></del>
    for d in soup.find_all('del'):
        d.decompose()

    airfields = []
    current_airfield = None

    for tr in soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
        if tr.td.span.text.isalpha():  # airfield
            if current_airfield != None:  # dont apend an empty airfield on the first loop
                airfields.append(current_airfield)

            # parse new airfield
            data = [''.join(td.stripped_strings) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            current_airfield = dict(zip(labels_airfield, data))
            current_airfield['runways'] = []
        else:  # runway
            data = [''.join(td.stripped_strings) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            current_runway = dict(zip(labels_runway, data))

            current_airfield['runways'].append(current_runway)

    # append last airfield
    airfields.append(current_airfield)

    return airfields
```

But when I run it, I have an error that say me this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "algo.py", line 85, in <module>
    airfields = parse_airfields()
  File "algo.py", line 69, in parse_airfields
    data = [''.join(td.stripped_strings) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
  File "/home/louis/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1255, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "/home/louis/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 525, in _find_all
    return ResultSet(strainer, result)
  File "/home/louis/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1712, in __init__
    super(ResultSet, self).__init__(result)
  File "/home/louis/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 522, in <genexpr>
    result = (element for element in generator
  File "/home/louis/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1273, in descendants
    current = current.next_element
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'
```

My BeautifulSoup version is the `4.4.0` but it works on a friend's computer who have the `4.3.2`.

What are the differencies between those versions ? How can I make the code run on my computer ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your and your friends python version 2.7 or 3.4?

Comment: Python 3.4.0, like me

Comment: ups, .../lib/python3.4 - beside this: if soup does not find the tag in the html it is None - type(soup.find('tbody')) - may you get an error page from your ip already

Comment: Are you sure it works with `4.3.2`, maybe the input html is different? Install it in a virtualenv to check: enable virtualenv and run `pip install 'beautifulsoup4==4.3.2'`

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I'm using it now... But I want it to work with BeautifulSoup 4.4.0!

Comment: What is `labels_airfield`?

Comment: A list with the dict name